# Android Studio build error - Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am unable to build my project in Android Studio.  I get the following error:

```
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] Unable to execute DX
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] com.android.dx.util.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:592)
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:550)
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:531)
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexBuffers(DexMerger.java:168)
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:186)
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:300)
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:232)
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:147)
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:276)
Error:Android Dex: [RaditazAndroid] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
```

However, this error means nothing to me.  It does not provide clues as to where I should begin fixing my project.  Has anybody encountered something similar?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, I solved my own problem.  My mistake was that I had pasted **android-support-v4.jar** and **google-play-services.jar** in all of my project's module lib folders (my project consists of 3 modules).  What I had to do instead was to paste these jars only into my main module's lib folder, and the other modules would automatically reference them.

Comment: this isnt the same cause for this issue i'm having... i'll post what i come up with for a solution when i get there

Comment: @JMRboosties  My experience has been that this error is due to duplicate jar files in lib folders.  Is yours not the case?

Comment: thx, solved. Having 2 copies of same sup library causes the error, i guess.

Comment: ty for solution and comments this saved a lot of time for me!

Comment: This worked, but I had to do a Rebuild Project to get the error to actually go away.

Comment: What if I've single module and gettin this error? @IgorGanapolsky

Comment: @NoOne This may be due to conflicting transitive dependencies in Gradle.  Run `./gradlew -q app:dependencies` to find out which ones.

Comment: I'm beginner. Where should I run this?

Answer (score 16):

Away from Android Studio, I opened the project in finder/workspace and did this:

1- MyProject folder -> build -> intermediate -> dex-cache -> cache.xml, and deleted all support-v4.jar items.

2- Also away from Android Studio, Went to every module in my project -> lib folder -> and deleted support-v4.jar as well.

Then cleaned the project and ran it and it worked thanks god :)

Comment: solution works, I had problems with okhttp-2.5.0.jar. Then completing steps the project was builded.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error.Solved it by adding to gradle file.

```
    dependencies{
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you have:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0') { exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4' }
```

in your project, add also:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
```

or

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

Comment: You saved my life after 3 days of work trying to figure out what happened with the AS nonsense. It is simply irritating to see that Google engineers are doing nothing to mitigate our pain.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was in module sdk version. I changed it from 2.2 to 4.4 and the problem was solved.

Comment: Do you mean minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion?

Comment: I meant builder's sdk version.
Look at: Project Structure->Modules->Module SDK

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error.

Removing a library(jtwitter.jar) form my-project/app/libs folder helped me.

Then cleaned the project and ran it and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Clean and rebuild was all it took for mine to start working.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else was having this problem with the Project Tango examples provided via [Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java), I solved it by commenting the following line out in the app's `build.gradle` file for those projects which failed to run:

`compile fileTree(dir: external_lib_prefix + '/jar', include: ['**/*.jar'])`

Answer (score 2):

I used a different approach by merging ABS res folder with my res folder and using ActionBarSherlock.jar as a global lib.

Works well so far and hope this help someone! But this is a hack since I was fed up of doing many things and I can't use Gradle since some of the other developers using Eclipse ADT without Gradle.

**Root Cause for the issue is using android-support-v4 in ABS and my project both and it's complicating DEX.**

Comment: Sounds good.  Supposedly you can use Gradle in Eclipse, although I've never tried it.  Anyhow, I'm in a similar position - where I use Gradle in Android Studio - and none of my teammates do.  But I found that I can still use it without conflicting with others.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue in Android Studio 2.3, in my case I had a mixture of version numbers which threw the build out, I changed:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For others wondering why this problem still persist even doing all other things suggested, This may help.

For me problem started when i added **Glide library**

```
dependencies {
  .........
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
  .........
}
```

and i had added already.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Which was contradicting with Glide support library somewhere.

Solution: Remove or downgrade your Glide support version.

```
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
```