# android studio how to use library dependencies already added in library module

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

```
--MyProject (module)
    --build.gradle
        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
            compile project ':MyLib'
        }
--MyLib (module)
    --build.gradle
        dependencies {
            compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.16'
            compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
        }
```

In my library module called **MyLib**, I've added (for example) Gson & Volley as library.

I wish to use `Gson` and `Volley` api in the `MyProject` module without adding the libraries again as dependencies but I can't. And when I add `Gson` or `Volley` in the `MyProject` `build.gradle`, it causes an error:

> multiple dex files define

How can I reuse dependencies that already added in the `MyLib` module? If this is not possible, how do I avoid this `multiple dex files define` error? I've tried [Android Studio Gradle Error: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851103/android-studio-gradle-error-multiple-dex-files-define)

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use the `Volley` and `Gson` libraries in each of your modules, you will need to add both libraries as dependencies in **both** of your `build.gradle` files (`MyProject` and `MyLib`).

As for the `multiple dex files define` error, I would try taking a look at these potential solutions:

- [Android Studio build error - Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301764/android-studio-build-error-multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4)
- [Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)

Good luck!